# Facebook, twitter, linkedin and google+ auth validation on backend/WS

Tags: facebook, authentication, twitter, google-plus, linkedin-api

I want to create application on iOS and Android where user can use Facebook, Google+, Twitter and LinkedIn to login and register to backend. Then I want to use WS to get data. Is it possible to validate on backend (WS) that user can access to data based on his credentials/tokens from those sites?